# Adventure game - walking around inside a room

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on an adventure game in Python using Pygame. My main problem is how I am going to define the boundaries of the room and make the main character walk aroud without hitting a boundary every time. Sadly, I have never studied algorithms so I have no clue on how to calculate a path. I know this question is quite general and hard to answer but a point in the right direction would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you controlling your main character yourself ? or is it some kind of AI moving around by itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read up on the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) search algorithm as it is commonly used in games for pathing problems.

If this game is two dimensional (or 2.5) I suggest you use a tile system as checking for collisions will be easier. Theres lots of information online that can get you started with these.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am currently looking into this http://www.pygame.org/project-AStar-195-.html

Answer (score 4):

There are two easy ways of defining your boundaries which are appropriate for such a game.

The simpler method is to divide your area into a grid, and use a 2D array to keep track of which squares in the grid are passable. Usually, this array stores your map information too, so in each position, there is a number that indicates whether that square contains grass or wall or road or mountain etc. (and therefore what picture to display). To give you a rough picture:

```
######
#.#  #
# ## #
#    #
######
```

A more complex method which is necessary if you want a sort of "maze" look, with **thin walls**, is to use a 2D array that indicates whether there is a vertical wall in between grid squares, and also whether there is a horizontal wall between grid squares. A rough picture (it looks a stretched in ASCII but hopefully you'll get the point):

```
 - - - -
| |     |
   - - 
|       |
 - - - -
```

The next thing to decide is what directions your character may move in (up/down/left/right is easiest, but diagonals are not *too* much harder). Then the program basically has to "mentally" explore the area, starting from your current position, hoping to come across the destination.

A simple search that is easy to implement for up/down/left/right and will find you the shortest path, if there is one, is called [Breadth-First search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Here is some pseudocode:

```
queue = new Queue #just a simple first-in-first-out
queue.push(startNode)
while not queue.empty():
    exploreNode = queue.pop()
    if isWalkable(exploreNode): #this doesn't work if you use
                                #"thin walls". The check must go
                                #where the pushes are instead

        if isTarget(exploreNode):
            #success!!!
        else:
            #push all neighbours
            queue.push( exploreNode.up )
            queue.push( exploreNode.down )
            queue.push( exploreNode.left )
            queue.push( exploreNode.right )
```

This algorithm is slow for large maps, but it will get you used to some graph-search and pathfinding concepts. Once you've verified that it works properly, you can try replacing it with A* or something similar, which should give the same results in less time!

A* and many other searching algorithms use a *priority queue* instead of a FIFO queue. This lets them consider "more likely" paths first, but get around to the roundabout paths if it turns out that the more direct paths are blocked.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for this thorough description. It helped me understand algorithms better! I am probably settling for the A* algorithm since it does most of the thinking for me :)

Size of the map might be a problem with A* though, since the current implementation I'm using (http://www.pygame.org/project-AStar-195-.html) works quite slowly with a 1024x768 map. Perhaps I should make every map tile bigger and decrease the total amount of tiles.

Comment: Why is your map so large? 1-pixel tiles are far too small. If you want your game world to be "hand drawn" rather than painted from tiles, a reasonable solution is to also draw an (invisible) map of passable/impassable areas, with say 4x4 pixels to each square in this map. You can also make A* "smarter" in various ways, for instance by making a distinction between "local" travel and "global" travel. Or you could just limit how far A* is willing to look, and otherwise force the user to click somewhere easier to get to.

Comment: Yes, 1-pixel tiles are definedly too small. To clarify, I am making my map suitable for a world with a 2.5D perspective (like Monkey Island 3 for instance). Even so, you are right in that I don't need 1px tiles. 4 or even 10pixel tiles would be well than enough. The tiles will be invisible. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I also plan to import the map from a svg for easy modification of each room.

Answer (score 3):

> Sadly, I have never studied algorithms so I have no clue on how to calculate a path.

Before you start writing games, you should educate yourself on those. This takes a little more effort at the beginning, but will save you much time later.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently looking into the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with pygame, but many applications commonly use [bounding volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume) to define the edge of some region. The idea is that as your character walks, you will check if the characters volume intersects with the volume of a wall. You can then either adjust the velocity or stop your character from moving. Use differing shapes to get a smooth wall so that your character doesn't get stuck on the pointy edges.

These concepts can be used for any application which requires quick edge and bounds detection.